# Embedding Matplotlib Animations in Python (google colab notebook)

Tags: matplotlib, animation, gif, google-colaboratory, animated-gif

I am trying to show a gif file in google's colab.research. I was able to save the file in the directory with the following path name `/content/BrowniamMotion.gif` but I don't know how to show this GIF in my notebook to present.

The code to generate the GIF so far, in case someone can manipulate it not to save the GIF but rather to animate it directly into the google colab file was,

```
# Other Brownian Motion
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

N=10
#val1 = 500

x=500*np.random.random(N)
y=500*np.random.random(N)

z=500*np.random.random(N)

def frame(w):
    ax.clear()

    global x,y,z
    x=x+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)
    y=y+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)
    z=z+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)


    plt.title("Brownian Motion")
    ax.set_xlabel('X(t)')
    ax.set_xlim3d(-500.0,500.0)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y(t)')
    ax.set_ylim3d(-500.0,500.0)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z(t)')


     ax.set_zlim3d(-500.0,500.0) 

        plot=ax.scatter

3D(x, y, z, c='r')


    return plot


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, frame, frames=100, blit=False, repeat=True)

anim.save('BrowniamMotion.gif', writer = "pillow", fps=10 )
```

Sorry if this question is badly, stated. I am new to Python and using colab research.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Colab it is easiest to use 'jshtml' to display matplotlib animation.

You need to set it up with

```py
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
```

Then, just type your animation object. It will display itself

```
anim
```

Here's a [workable colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ofuol9wHBJKxZlDS4foZ3cm9G8fArOow) of your code.

It has a slider where you can run back and forth at any point in time.

Comment: why do you get a duplicated frame displayed below the animation?

Comment: @JuanAlejandroGalvis use `IPython.display.display(anim)` to avoid the duplicated frame

Comment: Does this still work on google colab? I just executed it and it does not animate anything...

Comment: It's still work, but the duplicated frame keeps.  `IPython.display.display(anim)` didn't remove the duplicated frame for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link out on using the HTML to get it to work http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/ .

I didn't embed a link but instead imbedded a HTML video that got it to work.

```
# Other Brownian Motion
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

N=10
val1 = 600

x=val1*np.random.random(N)
y=val1*np.random.random(N)
z=val1*np.random.random(N)

def frame(w):
    ax.clear()

    global x,y,z
    x=x+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)
    y=y+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)
    z=z+np.random.normal(loc=0.0,scale=50.0,size=10)


    plt.title("Brownian Motion")
    ax.set_xlabel('X(t)')
    ax.set_xlim3d(-val1,val1)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y(t)')
    ax.set_ylim3d(-val1,val1)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z(t)')
    ax.set_zlim3d(-val1,val1) 

    plot=ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c='r')


    return plot


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, frame, frames=100, blit=False, repeat=True)

anim.save('BrowniamMotion.gif', writer = "pillow", fps=10 )
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Essentially all we did hear was add,

`from IPython.display import HTML` to the premable and then add the line `HTML(anim.to_html5_video())`.  This code then produces a video and saves the gif.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same authors git repository seems like we have a solution to embed the plots as GIFs ( [Save Matplotlib Animations as GIFs](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/save-matplotlib-animations-as-gifs/) ).

```
#!apt install ffmpeg
#!brew install imagemagick

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML, Image # For GIF

rc('animation', html='html5')
np.random.seed(5)


# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)


def generateRandomLines(dt, N):
    dX = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)

    dY = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(1, N)
    Y = np.cumsum(dY, axis=1)

    lineData = np.vstack((X, Y))

    return lineData


# Returns Line2D objects
def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[0:2, :num])

    return lines

N = 501 # Number of points
T = 1.0
dt = T/(N-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [generateRandomLines(dt, N)]

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2.0, 2.0), ylim=(-2.0, 2.0))

ax.set_xlabel('X(t)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y(t)')
ax.set_title('2D Discretized Brownian Paths')

## Create a list of line2D objects
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]


## Create the animation object
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateLines, N+1, fargs=(data, lines), interval=30, repeat=True, blit=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Save as GIF
anim.save('animationBrownianMotion2d.gif', writer='pillow', fps=60)

Image(url='animationBrownianMotion2d.gif')
## Uncomment to save the animation
#anim.save('brownian2d_1path.mp4', writer=writer)
```

[image]