# Animating 2 lines on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to animate two lines on the same plot. After searching around, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165233/two-lines-matplotib-animation) that seems to be getting me on the right track. When I run this code, the stagnant graph shows with no animation, giving me an error `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_data'`. I looked up `set_data` and it says it 'accepts: 2D array (rows are x, y) or two 1D arrays'. Is the animation not working since I'm assigning `line1` and `line2` to plots and not 2D arrays? I would appreciate any help with getting these lines to animate on my plot, I've tried and tried to no avail. Thanks!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

#Plot Lines
line1 = sns.lineplot('game_seconds_remaining', 'away_wp', data=game, color='#4F2683',linewidth=2)
line2 = sns.lineplot('game_seconds_remaining', 'home_wp', data=game, color='#869397',linewidth=2)
#Add Fill
ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'], 0.5, game['away_wp'], where=game['away_wp']>.5, color = '#4F2683',alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'], 0.5, game['home_wp'], where=game['home_wp']>.5, color = '#869397',alpha=0.3)


#Plot Aesthetics - Can Ignore
plt.ylabel('Win Probability %', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('', fontsize=16)
plt.axvline(x=900, color='white', alpha=0.7)
plt.axvline(x=1800, color='white', alpha=0.7)
plt.axvline(x=2700, color='white', alpha=0.7)
plt.axhline(y=.50, color='white', alpha=0.7)
plt.suptitle('Minnesota Vikings @ Dallas Cowboys', fontsize=20, style='italic',weight='bold')
plt.title('Min 28, DAL 24 - Week 10 ', fontsize=16, style = 'italic',weight='semibold')


#Labels (And variable assignment for animation below)
x = ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 3601,900))
y1 = game['away_wp']
y2 = game['home_wp']
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
x_ticks_labels = ['End','End Q3','Half','End Q1','Kickoff']
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_labels, fontsize=12)


#Animation - Not working
def update(num, x, y1, y2, line1, line2):
    line1.set_data(x[:num], y1[:num])
    line2.set_data(x[:num], y2[:num])
    return [line1,line2]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y1, y2, line1, line2],
                  interval=295, blit=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

it seems `sns` gives `AxesSublot` and you have to get `line(s)` for this `Axes`

```
ax1 = sns.lineplot(...)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(...)

line1 = ax1.lines[0]
line2 = ax2.lines[1]
```

Or (because both lines are on the same `Axes`)

```
sns.lineplot(x=x, y='away_wp', data=game)
sns.lineplot(x=x, y='home_wp', data=game)

ax = plt.gca()

line1 = ax.lines[0]
line2 = ax.lines[1]
```

---

**EDIT:**

For `Google Colab` it needs

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

# code without `plt.show()`

ani   # display it
```

Source: [Embedding Matplotlib Animations in Python (google colab notebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103994/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-python-google-colab-notebook)

---

Minimal working code with random data

```
import random
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

game = pd.DataFrame({
    'away_wp': [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(100)],
    'home_wp': [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(100)],
    'game_seconds_remaining': list(range(100)),
})

x = range(len(game))
y1 = game['away_wp']
y2 = game['home_wp']

fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()

sns.lineplot(x='game_seconds_remaining', y='away_wp', data=game)
sns.lineplot(x='game_seconds_remaining', y='home_wp', data=game)

line1 = ax.lines[0]
line2 = ax.lines[1]

ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'], 0.5, game['away_wp'], where=game['away_wp']>.5, color = '#4F2683',alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'], 0.5, game['home_wp'], where=game['home_wp']>.5, color = '#869397',alpha=0.3)
#print(ax.collections)

def update(num, x, y1, y2, line1, line2):
    line1.set_data(x[:num], y1[:num])
    line2.set_data(x[:num], y2[:num])

    ax.clear()
    ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'][:num], 0.5, game['away_wp'][:num], where=game['away_wp'][:num]>.5, color = '#4F2683',alpha=0.3)
    ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'][:num], 0.5, game['home_wp'][:num], where=game['home_wp'][:num]>.5, color = '#869397',alpha=0.3)

    return line1,line2

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y1, y2, line1, line2], interval=295, blit=False)

#plt.show()

ani   # display it
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same without `seaborn` but only `plt.plot()`.

At start I create empty line `line1, = plt.plot([], [])`

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

game = pd.DataFrame({
    'away_wp': [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(100)],
    'home_wp': [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(100)],
    'game_seconds_remaining': list(range(100)),
})

x = range(len(game))
y1 = game['away_wp']
y2 = game['home_wp']

fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()

# empty lines at start
line1, = plt.plot([], [])
line2, = plt.plot([], [])

# doesn't draw fill_between at start

# set limits 
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)

def update(num, x, y1, y2, line1, line2):
    line1.set_data(x[:num], y1[:num])
    line2.set_data(x[:num], y2[:num])
    # autoscale 
    #ax.relim()
    #ax.autoscale_view()

    ax.clear()
    ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'][:num], 0.5, game['away_wp'][:num], where=game['away_wp'][:num]>.5, color = '#4F2683',alpha=0.3)
    ax.fill_between(game['game_seconds_remaining'][:num], 0.5, game['home_wp'][:num], where=game['home_wp'][:num]>.5, color = '#869397',alpha=0.3)
    
    return line1,line2

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y1, y2, line1, line2], interval=295, blit=False)

#plt.show()

ani
```

[image]