# How to display a video in colab, using a PyTorch tensor of RGB image arrays?

Tags: python, video, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tensor

[image]I have a tensor of shape `(125, 3, 128, 128)`:

- 125 frames
- 3 channels (RGB)
- each frame 128 x 128 size.
- values in the tensor are in the range `[0,1]`.

I want to display the video of these 125  frames, using Pytorch in Google Colab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to enable inline animations in Colab is using [`jshtml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103994/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-python-google-colab-notebook):

```py
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
```

With this enabled, you can then plot your animation [like so](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html) (note you will need to [permute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641911) your image tensors to get them in PIL/matplotlib format):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

imgs = torch.rand(10,3,128,128)
imgs = imgs.permute(0,2,3,1) # Permuting to (Bx)HxWxC format
frames = [[ax.imshow(imgs[i])] for i in range(len(imgs))]

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames)
ani
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working for my code. Am I going wrong anywhere?   How can i put screenshot here?

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA can you be a bit more explicit about what is going wrong? Don't add a screenshot, add a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and the error output.

Comment: for i,[inp] in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
    print(inp.shape) #(8,3,128,128)
    from matplotlib import rc
    rc('animation', html='jshtml')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
    inp = inp.permute(0,2,3,1)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    frames = [[ax.imshow(inp[i])] for i in range(len(inp))]
    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames)
    ani
    break

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA your code appears to run fine on Colab for me with `inp = torch.rand(8,3,128,128)`. What exactly is the error / what looks wrong?

Comment: ouput is just a white square box with black border. When I use torch.rand, it is working as you said. but when i am using train loader it is not. Can i mail u screenshot?

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA The issue appears to be in your data then - the code I have posted expects RGB data either in the normalised [0,1] range or [0,255]. Can you add an example of your data to the question?

Comment: My data values in [0,1]. I was able to output jpg images. Can i use animation inside a for loop right for multiple videos?

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA oh I get the for loop now - yeah that's the issue. Remove the break, and plot one animation per cell.

Comment: I didn't get one animation per cell, how can I do that, please can you tell?

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA Add an example of your data (i.e. some samples from `train_loader`) to your question.

Comment: I added clear photo, can you suggest one "animation per cell" edit you stated earlier?

Comment: @SRIVINODPALACHARLA Save your animation objects to a container, and plot each one in a new cell. I'm not aware of a way to plot multiple animations in the same output in Colab (also, remove the break statement).